# how to bend a lattice around a sphere so that they are concentric?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, lattice

I am trying to use the bend modifier on a lattice at a 360 degree angle using the sphere as the Origin. I would like the lattice to become circular around the sphere so that lattice and sphere are concentric. However, I just cant figure out how to do that.
I have attached an image illustrating my problem.
Thank you,
Hidari
[image]